# How to break long url that containes hyphens

Tags: latex

I'm trying to break a long url using latex.
I have 3 links, the first one that contains hyphens doesn't work but the two others work because they don't contain hypens.

I used \url(the_url_to_brak) like this :

```
\hline 
\textbf{Documentation} & Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/guide/ebios-2010-expression-des-besoins-et-identification-des-objectifs-de-securite/}
& Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://clusif.fr/management_des_risques/}
& Catalogue de pratiques de sécurité et d’autres documents peuvent être téléchargés gratuitement sur \url{https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetID=309051}\\
```

This is the output :
[image]

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 6):

The `xurl` package will add more possible breaks points:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
\hline 
\textbf{Documentation} & Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/guide/ebios-2010-expression-des-besoins-et-identification-des-objectifs-de-securite/}
& Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://clusif.fr/management_des_risques/}
& Catalogue de pratiques de sécurité et d’autres documents peuvent être téléchargés gratuitement sur \url{https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetID=309051}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For such relatively narrow columns, it might look better to left align the text instead of justifying:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xurl}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYY}
\hline 
\textbf{Documentation} & Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/guide/ebios-2010-expression-des-besoins-et-identification-des-objectifs-de-securite/}
& Riche et peut être téléchargée gratuitement sur \url{https://clusif.fr/management_des_risques/}
& Catalogue de pratiques de sécurité et d’autres documents peuvent être téléchargés gratuitement sur \url{https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetID=309051}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have this error : LaTeX Error: File `xurl.sty' not found.

Comment: @PowerGirl Your tex distribution might be too old. This package was only added last year. Can you update?

Comment: I use online overleaf

Comment: @PowerGirl Please complain to the overleaf support, their tex distribution is terrible out of date, they still use texlive2017

Comment: @PowerGirl As a workaround, try to upload http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xurl/latex/xurl.sty to your project

Answer (score 0):

If you work on online overleaf with .cls file.
you can use "xurl" package.

```
\usepackage{xurl}
\newcommand{\doilink}[1]{\href{https://#1}{\url{#1}}}
```